# sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) NOT NULL constraint failed: user.words

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy

I've looked at the other posts with this same title, but they did not fix my problem. The error message in the above title is what I am getting.
I've made a simple database and constructor for the database. Just to test, I'm trying to add the word "hello" to the column "words" in the class User. But I keep getting this error. I've already tried putting autoincrement in the class column, but I ended it up getting another error. What is going wrong? Please see the code below. Python and Flask.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE URI"] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    words = db.Column(db.String(200), primary_key=True)
    
    def __init__(self, thewords):
        self.thewords = thewords

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

texts = "hello"
textstuffent = User(texts)
db.session.add(textstuffent)
db.session.commit()

results = User.query.all()
print(results)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('Textarea.html')

app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: In your `User` class, you set `self.thewords`, but you never set `words` which is the actual database column.

Comment: @John Gordon wait, the “words” column has to be set in the init?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who visits this page in the future, I've found what was wrong. I did not reference "words" as "self.words". My code now works and I am relieved to finally continue coding so that some other bug can confound me later down the road. Please see below. You can see the difference in code in the User class. I used query.all() to prove that data has made it into the database.

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from datetime import datetime
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE URI"] = 'sqlite:///test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):    
    words = db.Column(db.String(200), primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, thewords):
        self.words = thewords

db.create_all()
db.session.commit()

texts = "hello"
textstuffent = User(texts)
db.session.add(textstuffent)
db.session.commit()

print(User.query.all())

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def hello():
    return render_template('Textarea.html')
        
app.run(debug=True)
```